# If we don't create an object from a class, Class methods and size informations, still loading to ram on executing Program?

Tags: class, unity-game-engine, stack, heap-memory, ram

I am planning to code a card game in Unity/C#. In this game, every card will be a different class derived from main Card class. And they will override the Card virtual functions. My problem is, if there are 1000 cards and more, every card class methods and size informations will be loading to the ram on executing the game? If so, how we can manage this period? I just want to load classes data that cards in the player's deck to the ram. What are your suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This might be useful](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html).
Are you sure this is going to be a problem? Overloaded functions won't take up *that* much ram at all. Card art and things could I suppose...

Comment: So, i don't know how much place that holding on the ram. But 1000 Classes and their methods will be in ram when game start, even they are not being using. If this is not so much like 1,2 mb, it is not a problem. The cards arts, cant be loaded from the disk when they just called?

Comment: I guess memory wise this won't be a problem, but design wise you might want to take a different approach? I can't tell from the little information you posted, what the nature of your game is, but with composition and serialized data (that change the behavior of an instance), you can get a lot done without the need to create a subclass for each different card?

Comment: But, some cards will activate their effect when they gain life, and some cards will activate their effect when they attack. So implementing an  event listener for each effect(like gain health or attacking) looks like impossible. So i decided to choose this way. Some TCG games using lua (like yugioh devpro) but i don't know how to implement games with lua and i couldn't find  a lot of things about it in the internet...

Comment: Having an event listener for each effect will probably still be sensible

Comment: Thanks Jake, i am implementing event listener, let's see how much I can go further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think it might be a problem, create a quick test. It should be easy enough to create your main class with one or two virtual methods, and then create 100 derived classes, each one of which overrides the main class methods in the same way. Something like:

```
public class MainCard {
    // properties
    // 2 methods
}
```

Load and run your program (something simple that just instantiates a `MainCard` object), and determine how much memory it's taking.

Then, create 100 derived classes that override the methods in `MainCard`. The implementations of the overridden virtual methods can be identical.

```
public class Card01 : MainCard {
    // override both MainCard methods
}

public class Card02 : MainCard {
    // copy Card01 implementation here
}
```

Do that for 100 classes. See how much memory it takes.

Remember that in C#, the code for a class isn't necessarily even loaded into memory until an instance of the class is created, and then all you get is the metadata except for the functions that are actually called. The Just In Time compiler handles loading and compiling to native code on an as-needed basis. Unless you pre-compile on installation, of course.

Also remember, though, that once compiled the code will remain in memory throughout the life of the program. So if it's possible for every possible card to be used within a single game, then you do have to make sure that the compiled code for all cards will fit into memory.

Comment: This is actually what i want to know. Thanks for your answer Jim.